# How to create log cabin notched corners?

Tags: design

How can I create the notched corner look of the logs on the [LEGO IDEAS: Log Cabin](https://ideas.lego.com/projects/666c9a52-e3d2-4184-b964-03bc60ead3de)

[image: notched corner closeup]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, that's a digital model. This means it may use parts in colors we don't have. It looks like Reddish Brown is used here, so the part choice is rather limited.

Upon closer inspection of the model it looks like each corner has 2x2 column with round 2x2 bricks attached from each side as seen here:

[image]

I find using [Brick, Modified 1 x 1 x 1 2/3 with Studs on 1 Side](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32952#T=C) (which **is** available in Reddish Brown) in alternating manner to be the solution here. These bricks are exactly the size of 2x2 plate placed vertically, so no tiny gaps. And it also allows you to have as musch studs as possible on all sides.

[image]

Comment: Note that the entire 2x2 pillar of snot bricks not only support the log ends, but also support the logs themselves. You might want to update your answer to show how this would work.

Comment: Thanks @PhilB. for your comment. Until you posted this I thought "logs" have been attached in different way.

Comment: @PhilB. looking at the picture, there's a number of places where the "logs" appear to have smooth to smooth 2x2 round tiles - you can see the anti-stud gaps not all flowing the same way on each row.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid these two smooth looking tiles could actually be modified versions: 15535 (with hole, or anti-stud in the center) and 18674 (with stud in the center) to connect both end of the logs. However, since I prefer using Technic as much as possible (since it makes things much more rigid) in such case I'd use the tile with a hole on both ends and Technic axle to two make one long rigid log. The longer axle - the better.

Answer (score 7):

I may be misreading the question, but to answer what I think you're asking: They have used [Tile, Round 2 x 2 with Bottom Stud Holder with Tree Stump / Wood Grain Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=14769pb196&name=Tile,%20Round%202%20x%202%20with%20Bottom%20Stud%20Holder%20with%20Tree%20Stump%20/%20Wood%20Grain%20Pattern&category=%5BTile,%20Round,%20Decorated%5D#T=C&C=88), which has a printed pattern that looks like the end of a wood log with notches

[image: Circular tile with printed image of wood stump with notches]

Answer (score 2):

Given the color, I would think it's [Brick, Modified 1 x 1 with Stud on 1 Side](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87087), which (unlike many other similar bricks) is available in Reddish Brown. If you put two side-by-side, then you can hang the decorated round tile off it, and then put two more side-by-side, but pointing the **other** way to hang the next decorated round tile. You may need to add plates to space everything just right.

Comment: Perhaps you could also include a picture of partial assembly of the corner?